# Event handler do not load my JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I'm trying to insert text inside an element with id. However it do not appear. Why will it not load?

```js
function changeBio() {
  var objects = {
    name: 'Tobias',
    address: {
      country: 'Sweden',
      county: 'Stockholms Län',
      city: 'Stockholm',
    },
    age: 20,
    weight: 80.0,
  };

  var name = objects.name;
  var country = objects.address.country;

  document.getElementById('biography').innerHTML = 'My name is ' + name + ', I live in ' + country;
}
```

```html
<p id="biography"></p>

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    changeBio();
  };
</script>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cq00/050g68ck/2/

Comment: but not in jsfiddle

Comment: @AammadUllah: I saw it worked here now, but not in JSFiddle for some reason. Do you get it to work in JSFiddle?

Comment: In JSFiddle you have your JS configured to run onload, so `changeBio` isn't defined when the script in the script tags runs. Change it to be injected into the body or head instead. https://jsfiddle.net/050g68ck/4/

Comment: @AntP what changes did you make? Both the code looks exactly the same, am I missing something here?

Comment: @aManHasNoName - You can see the difference if you click on Javascript (with a gear wheel symbol) and check the Load Type.

Comment: @AntP Got it. Learnt something new here. Thanks!

Comment: This is why it is best to either a) use jsFiddle and other JavaScript playgrounds as they are intended (i.e. put the JavaScript in the JavaScript section and the HTML in the HTML section) or b) just use a local file on your computer. Browsers render JavaScript, HTML, and CSS locally just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is throwing error as "**VM743:74 Uncaught ReferenceError: changeBio is not defined**". bcoz "changeBio()" is being called first and then it is loading that function. 
you don't need to make explicit call

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    changeBio();
  };
</script>
```

this may help.

```
changeBio();
function changeBio() {
  var objects = {
    name: 'Tobias',
    address: {
      country: 'Sweden',
      county: 'Stockholms Län',
      city: 'Stockholm',
    },
    age: 20,
    weight: 80.0,
  };

  var name = objects.name;
  var country = objects.address.country;

  document.getElementById('biography').innerHTML = 'My name is ' + name + ', I live in ' + country;
}
```

or change when to load javascript functions as "in body" or "in head"  using gear icon .
see example :
https://jsfiddle.net/nk1506/zzsaf40k/

Answer (score -1):

Just change 
   load type 
to 
  No wrap in body inside jsfiddle
And put below code inside html

```
             <p id="biography">f</p>
```

And below inside javascript

```
     function changeBio() {
          var objects = {
               name: 'Tobias',
               address: {
               country: 'Sweden',
               county: 'Stockholms Län',
               city: 'Stockholm',
               },
             age: 20,
             weight: 80.0,
           };

    var name = objects.name;
    var country = objects.address.country;

    document.getElementById('biography').innerHTML = 'My name is ' + name +   ', I live in ' + country;
     }
          window.onload = function() {
             changeBio(); 
            };
```

and run it and you will be good to go

Comment: Please comment before down voting if you are brave, I have executed this code before posting here, So please use your down or upvote privillage as it supposed to be.

Answer (score -2):

It's working as intended when using `Run code snippet` here. Inside JSFiddle, it isn't working because your *JavaScript tab* is configured to run onload and your `onload` handler put inside *HTML tab* runs before it, so `changeBio` is not defined that time. I suggest you to put your `onload` handler also inside the *JavaScript tab* to keep all the script together then configure it to be wraped in `head` or `body`. Changed JSFidle here: https://jsfiddle.net/050g68ck/9/

Comment: Yes, you're right, changed my explanation to better explain the problem.